# distinguish a plain function from a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to determine wether a function in javascript is a simple, plain (anonymous) function, or a constructor ( a function with a prototype ). So far, I've come up with the following function:

```
function isPlainFunction(value) {
    var own = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value.prototype),
        ctorIndex = own.indexOf('constructor');

    if ( ctorIndex !== -1 ) {
        own.splice( ctorIndex, 1);
    }

    if (own.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // walk prototype chain
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(value.prototype);

    if (proto === Object.prototype) {
        return true;
    }

    return isPlainFunction(proto);
}
```

I'm only targeting ES5, (node.js) but I am uncertain whether this covers all edge cases, or if there's still something I havent found regarding this subject.

I have (roughly) the following testcases in mind:

```
assert.ok( isPlainFunction(function(){}) );

var bar = function(){};
bar.prototype = { get one(){ return 1 } };

assert.equal( isPlainFunction(bar), false );

var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype = Object.create( bar );

assert.equal( isPlainFunction(bar), false );
```

That is, any function that has a prototype or inherited a prototype from one of the not-native types...

Comment: Can you give an example of non-plain function (for which `isPlainFunction` should return `false`)?

Comment: There isn't really such a distinction. Every `function` can be used as a constructor, [including anonymous functions](http://jsconsole.com/?new%20function%20%28%29%20{%20this.foo%20%3D%20%27bar%27%3B%20}). The only separation is whether they're ever called with `new`.

Comment: Of course, as every function has `prototype` property. I see that the code checks whether or not this prototype is plain `Object`, and that makes sense. What I failed to understand is why there's two checks in this snippet.

Comment: @raina77ow The first checks if it should strip `constructor`. The second checks if there's anything remained. Could be done without the splice in a single check I guess. The last checks if we've reached Object.prototype, and should stop walking the prototype chain.

Comment: I've just added some rough example checks

Comment: @Jonathan I check for functions that have been instantiated with `new` before, and I know I cannot rule out constructors that set instance properties without a prototype without instantiating the thing first. And I filter for instances of known things first.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Actually, not *every* function can be used as a constructor.  Give this a try: `var s = new Array.prototype.slice();`  However, there's no way to make this kind of distinction in functions defined by users of ES5 -- only built-in functions can behave this way. (Note that `'prototype' in Array.prototype.slice` is `false` -- that's not possible for user-defined functions.)

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to test for is whether or not a function should be used as a constructor, then unfortunately this cannot be accurately determined.

You can invoke the `new` operator on any function, whether intended to be used that way or not without issues.

If I have this method, for instance:

```
function doSomethingWithThisObject(someValue) {
    this.someVariable = someValue;
}
```

Which has the following prototype:

```
doSomethingWithThisObject.prototype = { prototypeVariable : 'I came from prototype' };
```

I could use it in the following ways:

```
// Use my function as a constructor:
var obj = new doSomethingWithThisObject('hi there!');
console.log(obj.someVariable); // prints "hi there!"
console.log(obj.prototypeVariable); // prints "I came from prototype"

// Use my function in an object:
var myObject = {
    doSomething : doSomethingWithThisObject
};
myObject.doSomething('hi again!');
console.log(myObject.someVariable); // prints "hi again!"
console.log(myObject.prototypeVariable); // prints "undefined"

// Use my function to change global state:
doSomethingWithThisObject('you owe me ice cream!');
console.log(someVariable); // prints "you owe me ice cream!"
console.log(prototypeVariable); // prints "undefined"
```

Determining whether or not one of those use cases is the correct one is impossible unless the intention is specified somewhere in the code.

Some people suggest to name constructor methods with an uppercase first letter to determine that they should be used as constructors. If you decide for this suggestion with your project's coding guidelines, you could simply check if the function's name begins with an uppercase letter which would denote that the person who wrote the function intends for it to be used as a constructor.

Comment: Hi, what I'm trying to establish is whether the function has a prototype other then the inherited (native) Object.prototype. If this is the case, I'm assuming the function is intended as a constructor, not an anonymous or plain function. In your example, my isPlainFunction would return false, as you have specified a property on the prototype.

Comment: @matthijs Your function will return `true` if I do this: `var MyConstructor = function() {}; MyConstructor.prototype = { };`. However, it will return `false` if I do this: `var MyConstructor = function() {}; MyConstructor.prototype = Object.create(null);`. I could use both ways to achieve the exact same things.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Barkay has said, any function can become a constructor in JS through the *new* keyword. Behind the scenes all *new* is doing is setting the function's context -- you can see this with a simple test:

```
function test() {
     console.log(this)
}

test()
    output: Window {top: Window, window: Window…}
new test()
    output: test {}
            test {}
```

In JS all you need to make a function a constructor is a *new* keyword, and all a *new* does is set the function's *this* variable. So any function can become a constructor.

Distinguishing an anon function is easier: if it doesn't have a name, it's anonymous:

```
//anon:
(function() {
    console.log("I'm anon")
})()

var anon = function() {
    console.log("I, too, am anon")
}
```

If you programmatically need the function's name, you can get it through function.name

Comment: I have to add though, that the distinction for use intention between anonymous functions and named functions is still a mystery, because one is able to use an anonymous function as a constructor by assigning it to a variable the way that was demonstrated in this answer like so: `new anon();`

Comment: This is not an answer to the the question: can I reliably establish whether the function has a non-native prototype.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether a function does not have an extended `prototype`, e.g. can be assumed to be more then a plain function, the following function would return `false`:

```
   function isPlainFunction(value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'function') {
            return false;
        }

        var own = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value.prototype);

        if ( own.length >= 2 || ( own.indexOf('constructor') < 0 && own.length >= 1 ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return Object.getPrototypeOf(value.prototype) === Object.prototype;
    }
```